# Amazon EC2 permission(public key )denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, ssh-keys, public-key

I've been accessing my EC2 instance via SSH.  was able to connect using the original key. What is my problem??

```
$ ssh -vT 40.17.243.77
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 40.17.243.77 [40.17.243.77] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA ec:13:8q:9f:90:03:e3:c2:1c:3x:fa:7f:34:f2:7f:88
debug1: Host '40.17.243.77' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:12
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: rajesh@anonymous-media.com
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Amazon EC2 Permission denied (publickey)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826706/amazon-ec2-permission-denied-publickey)

Comment: @AndreyMyatlyuk - ssh ec2-user@[ec2 instance ip]. Unable to connect with remote server(Permission denied. Public key error)

Comment: I did not get your comment. I was asking whether you see the key for ec2 instance in the log above. If not, it means that ssh is not picking up the key.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the instance type, you probably need to specify the user.  For ubuntu, try ubuntu@IP, and for the Amazon Linux it's ec2-user@IP.